# LuaCOM x64 needed

Tags: lua, 64-bit, luacom

Can anyone use the open source files to code a 64bit version of the LuaCOM.DLL

I have the 32bit X86 version which worked just fine until the software developers for another application changed to a 64bit Lua, now the Link is broken